# Mvc attribute routing in area

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I wanna do url routing in my areas but its not working here its my controller code

```
 [RouteArea("Crooc")]
    [RoutePrefix("Home")]
    [Route("{action}")]
    public class HomeController : BaseController
    {
        HomeView mymodel = new HomeView();
        DTOCrooc _crooc = new DTOCrooc();
        GetUserInformations userInformation = new GetUserInformations();

        [Route("Default")]
        public ActionResult Index(int? page)
        {
```

and i configure RouteConfig.cs like that;

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

This attribute routing in area doesnt work but its working on a my base project

Comment: Make sure that this line `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();` appears somewhere in your `Application_Start`method.

Comment: yes i have this line of code in the global asax  like that ; AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

Comment: SO what URL are you typing in your browser to test that it not working?

Comment: localhost:50620/default  i'm trying like this.

Comment: Based on your routing attributes, to make it work you need to type /crooc/home/default

Comment: actually its not working crooc/home/default :(

Comment: this routing working on without area but in area its not working